# How to uninstall APC from a dedicated cpanel server using ssh

Tags: php, cpanel, apc

I want to uninstall APC caching software from my server. How to do that using ssh. My server OS is CENTOS 6.2 and php 5.2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit your php.ini file and remove the line that loads apc (something like `extension=apc.so`).

Your (correct) php.ini file can be located by running `php --ini`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using cpanel, you have to remove (or comment with ;) the line "extension=apc.so" from /usr/local/lib/php.ini and restart apache with /scripts/restarthttpd